# Drupal path linking to wrong content

Tags: 6, path-aliases, uri, emails

I have a content type for news. All my news nodes use the pathauto path: "node/[title-raw]". However, when I click to go to view any of my news items, instead of displaying the news item, the page displays a newsletter that was created using Simplenews. None of the normal Drupal content codes is being added. It's like it's just viewing a basic HTML page of the newsletter. Something is going wrong with the paths.

It seems like this newsletter has taken over all paths beginning "news...".

I'm not sure where to start looking for the problem. I would be grateful for any suggestions anyone has.

To see what I mean you can see the website at [www.signamic.co.uk](http://www.signamic.co.uk), and then click on any of the news items near the bottom.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: Do you have any tpl.php files for your news content type in your theme directory?  Do you by chance have a folder/directory named 'news' in your webistes directory?

Comment: Hi Citricguy - No, I have no special tpl.php files for news (I have just one custom tpl.php file for the front page). I also don't have a folder called 'news'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@citricguy exactly - seems that any URL you type after /news/ ends up showing your newsletter.

You probably have an index.html file there with that content.

Example:

http://www.signamic.co.uk/news/something-that-should-not-exist

Gives the same output as:

http://www.signamic.co.uk/news/full-time-pacourse-adminstrator-vacancy

Check your folder structure in root and .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi Ivanhoe123, thanks for your response. I had another look in the root folder and found I'd uploaded a test file called news.php. This was causing all the problems. Thank you very much for your (and Citricguy's) help.